# Unable to repeat comment string for new line

Tags: autocompletion, comments

Vim has the option to automatically continue comments when a new line is entered as described [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#format-comments). This currently works perfectly for `//` and `#` in .cpp and .python files respectively.

I tried to add the following line to the .vimrc for lisp

`autocmd filetype lisp,clojure           setlocal comments+=:;;`

I also tried to set it manually in a file via `:set comments=:;;`. All to no avail.

I have checked that vim is compiled with the `comments` flag set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `filetype`:

```
:set filetype?
```

It should show

```
filetype=lisp
```

If it is empty, then auto-comments would not work.

Same applies to

```
:set formatoptions?
```

The should look like

```
formatoptions=croql
```

and not be empty.

Comment: The important part was the `l` in `formatoptions`. Thanks.